# How to merge two pandas data frames filled with strings?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas Data frame like this:

```
      1      2     3     
 1 'taco'   NaN  'taco'
 2   NaN  'taco'  NaN
 3   NaN    NaN  'taco'
```

And another Pandas Data Frame Like this:

```
      1      2     3     
 1   NaN    NaN   NaN
 2 'Salt'   NaN  'Salt'
 3   NaN   'Salt' NaN
```

How do I combine my Pandas Data Frames such that I get something like this:

```
      1      2      3     
 1 'taco'   NaN   'taco'
 2 'Salt'  'taco' 'Salt'
 3   NaN   'Salt' 'taco'
```

Comment: `df1.fillna(df2)` / `df1.combine_first(df2)`

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have dataframes named `tacoDf` and `saltDf` and one should only fill `NaN` values from the other:

```
tacoDf.fillna(saltDf)
```